# Get location and directions of a mysql variable

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, directions

How can I user Google Map's API to get the directions and location for a variable.

Basically:

Say the variable is "harvard university", how can I get the location of it on a map, and directions/street view for that location and display it, like if you do a google search for "harvard university" on the right it comes up with the location, directions etc, how can I embed that into my website?

Thanks, I have tried to be as clear as possible.
[image: This is an example showing what I need to get and embed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding won't work for most business names. Try the Places Library:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into geocoding (The process of converting an address into geographical coordinates)
[Google geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Edit: Spelling